# can javascript version of print be inserted inside the code of a Div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that adds and subtracts a smaller form when user clicks on add or subtract users button.

what I want to do is add a +1 every time the user hits the add button to a ID tag inside the div tag.. confusing yes I know
say this is the original tag:

```
<div id="formwrap" class="test" name="test">im a form in this formwrap</div>
```

now say the user clicks on a add button and a new form will pop up below the current form and using a print or echo version of javascript this would be the new code created for the div using  .append(html) or something along those lines too this:

```
<div id="formwrap" class="test" name="test">im a form in this formwrap</div>
<div id="formwrap" class="test2" name="test2">im a form in this formwrap</div>
```

and so on as u can see next the 2 would change to a 3 if someone where to click the add button

```
<div id="formwrap" class="test(+1 code would go here)" name="test(+1 code would go here)">im a form in this formwrap</div>
```

So before I code is this even possible? I want to be able to style the smaller form differently and I want the phpmailer to be able get retrieve all the data depending on how many clicks they do. and adding a +1 too each of the tags would do both goals.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to create DOM elements that have the same ID, it's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using data attributes.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

You would do something like this

```
var count = 0
var formwrap = document.getElementById('formwrap');
formwrap.dataset.name = "aName" + count
// increment count on click
```

Comment: So lets say i add 4 people that would make them name="1",name="2",name="3",name="4" when user hits submit POST would pull data from all 4 inputs right? when I right click and view source its not there. i threw this together for you so u can get an idea
https://jsfiddle.net/8frqx97h/38/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this when user click on add button you have to increment the value of count like this ...

```
    var count = 0;
    $("button").on("click", function () {
       var html = '<div id="formwrap'+count+'" class="test'+count+'"
                  name="test'+count+'">im a form in this formwrap</div>';
       count++;
       $(div).append(html);
   });
```

this way you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Create a private counter var
const counter = (function() {
  var formCount = 0;
  return {
    value: () => formCount,
    increment: () => ++formCount
  }
})();

//A function that will generate a "form" element
const ID_PREFIX = 'formwrap_';
const generateFormEl = () => {
  let el = document.createElement('div');
  el.setAttribute('id', `${ID_PREFIX}${counter.increment()}`);
  el.setAttribute('class', 'test');
  el.setAttribute('name', 'test');
  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`ID: ${el.getAttribute('id')}`));
  return el;
};

//Store your DOM elements in some vars
const forms = document.querySelector('#forms');
const btn = document.querySelector('[type="button"]');

//Add a form element to the DOM on click
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const form = generateFormEl();
  forms.appendChild(form);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="button" value="Add a form" />
  <div id="forms"></div>
</div>
```